# Finding 1870 Federal Census image that corresponds to street address in Albany City, New York, USA?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, census-records, new-york-state, address

From *Ancestry.com. U.S. City Directories, 1821-1989 [database on-line]. Provo, UT, USA: Ancestry.com Operations, Inc., 2011* I know that in 1870 my 4th great grandfather Hugh Sellars was living or at least running a variety store at 311 Washington Ave, Albany City, New York State, USA.

[image]

According to the same *U.S. City Directories* he had been there since at least 1864 and stayed there until at least 1872.  However, while I have found him in the 1865 New York State Census, I have not been able to locate him in the 1870 Federal Census.

Using my subscription to Ancestry.com, or any other means, is it possible to determine which image(s) from the 1870 Federal Census I should be trying to look at?

My problem seems to be the opposite of that in [How to find address of building in New York State censuses (1870, St Lawrence, USA)?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/4093/how-to-find-address-of-building-in-new-york-state-censuses-1870-st-lawrence-u)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For descriptions of census subdivisions and enumeration districts, see the following resources:

- NARA's publication T1224, Roll 3 (see the downloadable PDF, [Descriptions of Census Enumeration Districts, 1830-1890 and 1910-1950](http://www.archives.gov/research/microfilm/t1224.pdf)).
- William Thorndale and William Dollarhide's [Map guide to the U.S. federal censuses, 1790-1920](https://www.worldcat.org/title/map-guide-to-the-us-federal-censuses-1790-1920/oclc/16509993&referer=brief_results)
- William Dollarhide and Gordon Lewis Remington, [New York State censuses & substitutes : an annotated bibliography of state censuses, census substitutes, and selected name lists in print, on microform, or online : with county boundary maps, 1683-1915 : and state census examples and extraction forms, 1825-1925](https://www.worldcat.org/title/new-york-state-censuses-substitutes-an-annotated-bibliography-of-state-censuses-census-substitutes-and-selected-name-lists-in-print-on-microform-or-online-with-county-boundary-maps-1683-1915-and-state-census-examples-and-extraction-forms-1825-1925/oclc/70254345&referer=brief_results)

An article on the Iowa USGenWeb site, [Enumeration District Descriptions and Maps](http://iagenweb.org/state/census/nara/edmaps.htm) says:

> The title of T1224 contains a misnomer because EDs, strictly defined,
>   were not used until the 1880 census. The early censuses used the term
>   **subdivision** to refer to part of a supervisor's or marshal's division
>   or district. Subdivisions in the early censuses comprised towns,
>   townships, or other units comparable to MCDs.

MCD is a US Census Bureau abbreviation for [Minor civil division](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/Minor+Civil+Division).

Other resources:

- [David Rumsey Map Collection](http://www.davidrumsey.com/)
- [Sanborn Fire Insurance Maps](http://www.loc.gov/rr/geogmap/sanborn/)
- [Selected Maps, Gazetteers and Geographical  Resources](http://www.nysl.nysed.gov/reference/maps.htm) at the New York State Library
- [Atlas of Historical County Boundaries](http://publications.newberry.org/ahcbp/pages/New_York.html) (includes shapefiles) at Chicago's Newberry Library
- US Census Bureau: [Albany County, New York QuickLinks](http://quickfacts.census.gov/qfd/states/36/36001lk.html) (mostly modern data, but I include the link in case the Bureau decides to include map data in their QuickLinks beta)

Using a combination of maps and information from city directories and other records that give street addresses, you can narrow down the possibilities for the sheet you need.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because I am confident that the systematic approach it espouses would have been far more effective in 95% of cases than the lucky strike in my answer.

Comment: @PolyGeo the most effective approach is to use both techniques together.   I've used Stephen P. Morse's [One-Step Web Pages](http://www.stevemorse.org/) to make searches by first name only and an age range many, many times.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is possible for US Fed. Census records prior to 1880.  Before that census, the records don't indicate the addresses of the individuals.

Beginning in 1880 they do start to include street address information and you can use a tool like http://stevemorse.org/census/unified.html to identify which Enumeration District an address was in, and then open up the Ancestry viewer from this site for the pertinent information,

Comment: I think what I may try to do is look through the directory for someone not far from 311 Washington and see if I can find them in the census to get within an image or few that way.

Answer (score 1):

I just made a very lucky strike by using an Ancestry search for anyone named Mary (Hugh's wife's name), born 1805+/-5 years, from England, in Albany Ward 9 of the 1870 Federal Census.  Looking at Results 1–20 of 173,778 returned by the search, I was almost not bothered to go to the next page when I saw:

> Mary Sallan Albany Subdivision 335, Albany, New York  abt 1804    England

I viewed the record to see:

```
Hugh Sallan 67
Mary Sallan 66
Caroline Foster 12
Henry A Elliot  25
```

Caroline was also in the household of Hugh and Mary for the 1865 New York State Census and Hugh's occupation is given as Variety Store so I am very confident that this is the record I was after.

The image is quite difficult to read, and may lead to me asking a separate question or two, but Hugh's birthplace had been incorrectly transcribed as Ireland when I read it as the expected Scotland.

The source citation is:

> Year: 1870; Census Place: Albany Subdivision 335, Albany, New York;
>   Roll: M593_899; Page: 676B; Image: 620; Family History Library Film:
>   552398

Comment: Now that you know you are looking for Subdivision 335, you can look for a map to see what streets are in that subdivision.