# How to locate 1940 United States census pages by address?

Tags: census-records, 1940s, address, indexing, texas

I'm not able to locate a George Bismark Foster, married to Ola Kathleen Mundy in the 1940 census records by name search.  I know they were still alive because I have found an April 27, 1942 WWII draft registration card that lists them both as living at 4237 University Blvd., Dallas, Dallas County, Texas.  According to George's death certificate, they moved to Dallas in 1934.  Therefore, I think it is very likely that for the 1940 census they were living in Dallas, and that it was probably also at 4237 University Blvd in 1940.

Therefore, I'd like to find the 1940 census records for University Blvd in Dallas and search the page to try and find their record.

Using Ancestry.com or FamilySearch.org, how can I locate the 1940 census pages for that street in Dallas?  Is there an index by location I can use?  Can I determine the voting district and use that to find the right pages?

Comment: This answer to another question may be useful to you: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/8053

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the page here:

https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.3.1/TH-1942-27818-9190-18?cc=2000219

By using this tool:

http://stevemorse.org/census/unified.html

To look up the address of University Blvd. in the county of Dallas and city of University Park (not Dallas) which has the University Blvd listed.  I then entered the cross streets by looking up the address on maps today to see that it is between the cross streets of Douglas Ave. and Winchester Dr.

This gave me two 1940 ED numbers: 57-8D, 57-8F

I searched these one page at a time and found the even side of the block was in 57-8D and the odd side that I needed was on 57-8F.

Unfortunately, they were not at that address in 1940 according to the census, so I'm back to wondering where in Dallas they were and why the name lookup does not find them.

I then decided to search by just George and Ola (without any last name) in Dallas, Texas and born between 1889 and 1892 and got paydirt, under the incorrectly transcribed name Jaster!

https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:K4QR-84N