# Understanding Surnames On Vital Records From Peru

Tags: surnames, vital-records

I'm trying to understand how to create legitimate records from documents written in Spanish from Peru.  It seems like two surnames are often used.  I have an idea of what the last names are supposed to be, but then my genetic grandmother's death certificate looks like they list her son on it with her surname instead of his.  Then there are other questions, such as her death certificate listing her being from Ancash, but I tried to Wikipedia it and it seems like Ancash is not only a large area, but a small area in lima as well.  I found some Christening records that look like they might fit, based on other records that don't fit with her name, but it also adds Huaylas, to the Ancash, Peru designation.

I read [Researching genealogy in Peru](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/14324/researching-genealogy-in-peru) on here about someone looking for her mother's ancestors which had a set of good places to look for records, but it was 3 years old and seemed to be more link based as opposed to understanding surname nomenclature as they relate to vital records.

Can anyone help me to understand the surname hurdle?

Unfortunately, I was not a legitimate birth (when asked, they don't want to talk about it), but I am getting DNA matches and questions I'd like to be able to answer.

Comment: They may well use Spanish naming customs where children have two surnames, one from each parent - see https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/4111/45 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_naming_customs for more information.

Comment: I suggest that you Google "Peruvian Naming Customs" - there are a number of references. Yes, it does appear that Spanish is the root but to what extent there are any differences, I've no idea. Wikipedia has an article on naming customs of Hispanic America but oddly it doesn't mention Peru. Several of those links mention useful clarifications to answer What-ifs.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.

Comment: https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Peru_Personal_Names is relevant