# What reference materials discuss any "known issues" in the microfilms of 1930 US Federal Census?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, census-records, 1930s

I have been unable to locate some of the families I'm researching in the 1930 Census (for one example see my question [What are good search techniques for finding people who have moved within the same geographical area?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3922/what-are-good-search-techniques-for-finding-people-who-have-moved-within-the-sam)).

One well-known guide for US Federal Census information is William Thorndale and William Dollarhide's book [Map Guide to the U.S. Federal Censuses, 1790-1920](http://www.genealogical.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&item_number=5786).  However, this work does not include the 1930 Census.  What other Guides exist for 1930?

Some basic information can be found at:

- The portal [1930 Federal Population Census](http://www.archives.gov/research/census/1930/) at NARA
- The Ancestry.com Wiki (wikified from their reference work The Source) article on [1930 U.S. Census](http://www.ancestry.com/wiki/index.php?title=1930_U.S._Census)
- The FamilySearch Wiki article [United States Census 1930](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/United_States_Census_1930)
- The FamilySearch Wiki article on [United States Census, 1930 (FamilySearch Historical Records)/Known Issues](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/United_States_Census,_1930_%28FamilySearch_Historical_Records%29/Known_Issues)

Where else might I find information about other "known issues" with the 1930 US Federal Census?  Could there be EDs or pages within EDs which did not get microfilmed?

Comment: BYU has a tutorial for searching the US Census; under tips for 1930 they say "Microfilm roll 1602 (New York) was skipped during the original filming and is unavailable to search." http://census.byu.edu/project_files/xml/page11.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1930 Census of Population

The 1930 US Population Census, NationalArchives and Records Administration microfilm publication T626, Fifteenth Census of the United States, 1930 (2667 rolls).
[T626](http://www.census.gov/history/pdf/t626.pdf)

The 1930 census and all existing Soundex indexes are available at the National Archives Building,700 Pennsylvania Ave., NW ,Washington, DC20408-0001; the Archives' regional facilities around the country; many public libraries; and for a fee at online commercial genealogy sites.