# Finding records prior to 1838 for Malone, Franklin County, NY or St. Lawrence County, NY?

Tags: birth-records, surnames, new-york-state, marriage-practices

How or where does one find records prior to 1838 for Franklin & St. Lawrence County, NY?

Hiram Wheeler Barlow (28 Sep 1820-27 Aug 1876) and his ancestry (parents).

- It is believed he was born in upstate New York, USA. State Census records record St. Lawrence County, military records say Malone, Franklin County.
- Both genealogical societies report they have no records of him or his parents.

I can trace him after he and his family settled in Oswego, Oswego Co., New York, but not before than, except for his participation in the Battle of the Windmill in 1838.

It is believed he married Mary CUMMINS/COMMINS of Augusta, Grenville, Ontario, Canada daugther of James CUMMINS and Charity ROOD/ROODE/RUDE. It is there in Canada where they had there first three children, Harriet, Henryett, and Hervey. The other two are believed to have been born in Oswego, NY, Aseneth, and Hiram Jr. after which Mary died.

He married second to Mary Frances SANTEE-MORROW. Two additional children were born to this second marriage, Ziplha, and Hettie.

I have been told that his parents where Noah Barlow and Mary Dempsey Adams, also his mother was actually a Wheeler. So far to date I've found no records or documentation on either.

Would love to learn more about Hiram Wheeler Barlow and his ancestry (parents) and also that of his first wife Mary CUMMINS. Also, would love to document Their marriage and the birth of their children.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. It sounds as though you have an interesting family history project underway and I am certain that the expertise available on this site will be of help to you. BUT any question that begins "I am looking for any information on .. " is unlikely to do much good. People here will not do your research for you. They will assist you to deal with specific questions. Can you edit what you have written to isolate one thing that you need help with? My guess is that will concern "How do I find the parents of ...?"

Comment: @JayStone, I created some breaks in the body of your question. I hope it helps keep the information and the two wives a bit more clear. If you aren't pleased with the change, you can view the history and roll it back.

Comment: @PolyGeo I have changed the tags and removed "Canada" and added "New York State".  The question title and the question at the top of the main question, and all the previous answers, address the problem of finding records for these two counties in New York State.  If this question had been from an active member of the community, we could have encouraged a second question to explore the options for Canadian records, but I don't see the point in having this question tagged Canada for a passing reference.

Comment: I agree @JanMurphy - good pick up.

Answer (score 5):

Before I post some ideas, it would be good to remind everyone that, at least at some point, New York state was one of those places genealogists referred to as a "[black hole](http://archiver.rootsweb.ancestry.com/th/read/APG/2002-04/1019828647)?"

Here are some suggestions for resources:

- Marian S. HENRY, [*New York essays: resources for the genealogist in New York state outside New York City*](http://www.worldcat.org/title/new-york-essays-resources-for-the-genealogist-in-new-york-state-outside-new-york-city/oclc/180161545&referer=brief_results) (Boston, MA, New England Historic Genealogical Society, 2007).
- Janes Wethy Foley, *Early Settlers of New York State: Their Ancestors and Descendants* (multiple volumes)
- *[The New York State Archives](http://www.archives.nysed.gov/a/research/res_topics_genealogy.shtml)*: Genealogy Resources
- *[American Ancestors](http://www.americanancestors.org/home.html)*, among other things, for its database "Abstracts of Wills, Admins. and Guardianships in NY State, 1787-1835." Possibly also for its "American Canadian Genealogical Society Index of Baptisms, Marriages, and Burials, 1840-2000."
- *[The New York Genealogical and Biographical Record](http://www.newyorkfamilyhistory.org/nygbr)*, published continuously since 1870; it is the scholarly journal of the New York Genealogical & Biographical Society (see Duncan's answer); also, the [society's website](http://www.newyorkfamilyhistory.org/).
- FamilySearch Catalog: [Franklin County (New York) resources](https://familysearch.org/search/search/library_catalog#searchType=catalog&filtered=true&fed=false&placeName=New+York,+Franklin&catSearchType=place). Includes "Deed records, 1808-1900" (seems all indexed); "Mortgage records, 1808-1853" (index for 1808-1873); Samuelsen's "Franklin County, New York will testators index, 1809-1919"; Probate records, 1839-1927; Wills, 1809-1905; various accountings of vital records and notices.
- New York Historical Resources Center (Cornell University), [*Guide to historical resources in Franklin County, New York, repositories*](https://familysearch.org/search/catalog/show?uri=http://catalog-search-api:8080/www-catalogapi-webservice/item/539308), c1987. (Includes link to online version)
- FamilySearch Catalog: [St. Lawrence County (New York) resources](https://familysearch.org/search/search/library_catalog#searchType=catalog&filtered=true&collectionId=&fed=false&page=1&catSearchType=place&searchCriteria=&placeName=New+York,+St.+Lawrence&author_givenName=&author_surname=). Includes deeds and mortgage resources dating to 1808 (appears indexed); Samuelsen's "St. Lawrence County, New York will testators index, 1809-1919"; Probate records, 1830-1919; indexes, 1830-1955; Miscellaneous civil, court, and military records, 1844-1902; Court records, 1802-1806 (Common Pleas); Court records, 1802-1806 (General Sessions); various accountings of vital records and notices.
- New York Historical Resources Center (Cornell University), *[Guide to historical resources in St. Lawrence County, New York repositories](https://familysearch.org/search/catalog/show?uri=http://catalog-search-api:8080/www-catalogapi-webservice/item/576052)*, ca1987.
- Town and county historians. "Nearly every county, town and borough [in New York]" has an officially appointed Historian. (See "[New York State County Historians](http://www.nysm.nysed.gov/research_collections/research/history/hishistorians.html).")

I'm sure the above list could be improved upon (newspapers, maps, church records jump out at me). While it is not on the list, I would contact a library in each of the towns where my ancestor lived. Often times there are special collections or special indexes that are available.

1. If you don't use a research log, I would encourage you to start one. I wrote about research logs on Genealogy.SE. See my answer on "[What details should I be recording ...](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/2202/7)."
2. Document all the information you believe you know about your family. Even if you don't use a formal citation style, keep track of all the sources. It is important to know exactly how you came to learn each bit of information. If you have different, conflicting facts about dates and locations--record them all and source each one.
3. Try to research at the family group level--meaning that you conduct cradle to grave research about each of Hiram's wives and all of his children. This kind of research not only uncovers more clues about Hiram, but it will help you establish a really good timeline--where he most likely was at specific time periods. (This very much helps you figure out which records to search.)
4. Try to search broadly, but in specific resources; make notes/keep a list of "interesting names" that you find in each resources.

My biggest break throughs  haven't come from vital records (other than marriage records, [vital records don't exist about my family](https://bettergedcom.wikispaces.com/Ancestors+for+Sale) from a little after 1800 until well into the 20th century). My break throughs have been made working with deeds, probate files, court records and maps. More recently, one came from really ugly looking church record written in old German script.

Good luck.

P.S. When I was pulling the database titles from the American Ancestors site, I did a random search for the name "Wheeler Barlow" in "Abstracts of Wills, Administrations and Guardianships in NY State, 1787 - 1835" (part of the database group, "Court Land and Probate Records"). There was a hit; indexed as Joseph Wheeler Barlow; 1803, Stamford, Delaware County, New York. Searching all of American Ancestors databases for just the surname "Barlow," limited only to "New York," resulted in almost 800 returns; 172 of which were in "Court, Land and Probate Records."

Answer (score 2):

The [New York Genealogical and Biographical Society](http://www.newyorkfamilyhistory.org/) might be a place to look.

Its website claims:

> "The New York Genealogical and Biographical Society is the oldest
>   genealogical society in New York State and the second oldest in the
>   nation. ... The NYG&B is the most authoritative source for research
>   on New York families and families with New York connections. Founded
>   in 1869, it is the largest genealogical society in New York and the
>   only one that is state-wide."

Answer (score 1):

Since the other answers were posted, the New York Genealogical and Biographical Society has published a massive research guide:

- [New York Family History Research Guide and Gazetteer](http://newyorkfamilyhistory.myshopify.com/collections/products/products/copy-of-new-york-family-history-research-guide-and-gazetteer-pre-order-member)

I agree with the suggestion to ask about indexes and guides to special collections in libraries and archives -- in any library or archive, but especially in local ones.

- [Genealogy Resources for Northeastern New York](http://cefls.libguides.com/content.php?pid=384712) at the Clinton Essex Franklin Library System
- [branch directory for the North County Library System](https://web.ncls.org/library-listing) (several branches have genealogy departments which may have their own guides and lists of collections)

Other guides to New York State resources:

- USGenWeb (hosted by RootsWeb): [New York State Off-line Sources](http://www.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~nysource/) -- see the [County](http://www.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~nysource/county.htm) link to search by county.  The site includes some material about the WPA's Historical Records Survey
- BYU's [New York Research Outline](http://files.lib.byu.edu/family-history-library/research-outlines/US/NewYork.pdf)

Historical Newspaper Resources include:

- [Fulton History / Old Fulton Post Cards](http://fultonhistory.com/Fulton.html)
- *The Ancestor Hunt* -- [New York State Newspapers -- Mapped!](http://www.theancestorhunt.com/blog/new-york-state-newspapers-online-mapped#.VWyM1UZ0JT8) and 
  [New York Online Historical Newspapers Summary #1](http://www.theancestorhunt.com/blog/new-york-online-historical-newspapers-summary1#.VWyNIEZ0JT8)
- Miriam J. Robbins' [New York Online Historical Newspapers](https://sites.google.com/site/onlinenewspapersite/Home/usa/ny) and [New York Online Historical Directories - listed by county](https://sites.google.com/site/onlinedirectorysite/Home/usa/ny)

It can also help to use a Genealogical Source Checklist -- for an example, see this list from the [Capital Area Genealogical Society (Harrisburg, Pennsylvania)](http://www.capitalareagenealogy.org/forms/GenSrcChkLst.pdf).  They also have a handout on [Overcoming Brick Walls and Dead Ends](http://www.capitalareagenealogy.org/documents/Brickwalls_Deadends.pdf) and other useful materials.  Similar forms and guides can be downloaded from many sites -- see the FamilySearch Research Wiki articles [Solving Tough Research Problems](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Solving_Tough_Research_Problems%E2%80%94Overcoming_Brick_Walls) and [United States | How to Find Genealogy Records](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/United_States,_How_to_Find_Genealogy_Records).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try to reach out to the Genealogical Research team at the Franklin County Historical & Museum Society in Malone, NY.  Email:  fcohms@northnet.org Website:  www.franklinhistory.org